# Merging Multiple Queries - Same Table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 1 table called itemmovement : It has Item Id , Quantity In , Quantity Out , Invoice Id, Date. I need to make in one query to show how many pieces are sold and beside the sold column there will be the current on hand quantity .

itemmovement

```
Id   itemid      qtyin     qtyout    invid    purchasereturnid          date
1     1            10                                                2019-01-04
2     2            8                                                 2019-01-06
3     2                      2         1                             2019-01-08
4     1                      3         2                             2019-01-12
5     2            1                                                 2019-02-04
6     3            4                                                 2019-03-04
7     1                      1         3                             2019-04-04
8     1                      1                      1                2019-04-14
9     3                      1                      2                2019-04-24
```

I need the query to show this result

```
Id   itemid      Sold Quantity   OnHandQty
1     1               4             5
2     2               2             7
3     3               0             3
```

I'm Trying to use this query but not working

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT itmv.itemid,
          sum(itmv.qtyout)-sum(itmv.qtyin)
   FROM itemmovement itmv
   WHERE (itmv.systemdate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-06-01')
     AND invid>0
   GROUP BY itmv.itemid) AS result1,

  (SELECT sum(itmv2.qtyin)-sum(itmv2.qtyout)
   FROM itemmovement itmv2
   WHERE itmv.itemid=itmv2.itemid
   GROUP BY itmv2.itemid) AS result2
ORDER BY sum(itmv.qtyin)-sum(itmv.qtyout)
```

I'm getting :

> Unknown column 'itmv.itemid' in 'where clause it for this syntax :
>
> where itmv.itemid = itmv2.itemid

Comment: At first look, the syntax error seems to be because you're referencing the alias `itmv` in your second `SELECT` where it can no longer be referenced.  You can try changing it to `result1.itemid`, but your query still may need re-working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your query.

```
select itemid
    , sum(case when COALESCE(invid,0) > 0 then qtyout else 0 end) as Sold_Qantity
    , sum(qtyin)-sum(qtyout) as OnHandQty
from itemmovement
group by itemid
```

Comment: @Metal , the sold quantity are only the qty out for the sold items (invoiced = invid>0)

Comment: what if i want to check between two cases(fields) like (invid>0 OR invid2>0) what will be my case

Comment: `case when COALESCE(invid,0) > 0 or  COALESCE(invid2,0) > 0  then qtyout else 0 end`